# what is the jquery opposite of this :not() command

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get all option values that have no attribute value.  So I want it to retrieve options setup like `<option value></option>` entries.

I have `$('#advancedSearchWrap option:not([value=""])')` but what I need is the opposite.  What is the opposite of this :not() command?

Comment: You can `:not` the `:not` to get the opposite (`:not`-ception): `option:not(:not([value=""]))` :-P  No, but, seriously, just remove `:not` to get the opposite: `option[value=""]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply use the regular CSS attribute selector:

```
$('#advancedSearchWrap option[value=""]');
```

Comment: Exactly. The opposite of `:not` is *removing* it.

Answer (score 21):

If instead of *not* you wanted *only* you could use `filter()`

Answer (score 6):

This also works.

```
$morphemes.not('[data-width]');
$morphemes.not(':not([data-width])'); //Double Negative logic, derp derp.
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just minus the :not selector? remove it from your expression and it should work.

Comment: There are edge cases where you need the opposite of `not`, for example selecting `a` elements without an `href` as well as `a` elements with `href="#"`, you could use something like: `a:not([href^="#"]):not(":not([href])")`